# Import one project packages into another project packages in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

A few months back , I'm create a project that's name is products in which i'm using spinner,imageswitcher,shopping cart and some other activities to create ecommerce site .Recently ,i.m create a new project that's name is scanner, in this i integrate a scanner using zxing libaray for scanning QR code.The problem is that i want to add all my product activities in this scanner project. When i copy all packages of product project and paste it into scanner project,the logcat show no error but console display that some features missing.I don't understand the problem,i checked all the activities. Is this possible to import one project into another project.How could i do this?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? What errors does eclipse show? Not logcat but actually in the error console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set products project to be a library project :
Right click on project in Eclipse -> properties -> Android -> check isLibrary.

In your scanner project do:
Right click on project in Eclipse -> properties -> Android -> Add -> select products.

Now your can use anything that's defined in products from scanner project.