# Gradle error when importing one Android Studio project into another using import module method

Tags: java, android, import, module

I am trying to import this  https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop project into an existing android studio project so as to utilise its functionality.

I found this article: [Import one project packages into another project packages in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600796/import-one-project-packages-into-another-project-packages-in-android) - which I followed.

However, when I try to import the android-crop project as a module I get this error:

```
Error:(12, 0) Could not find property 'VERSION_CODE' on project ':cropperMod'
```

cropperMod referring to the name I gave the module upon the import.

I've managed to import the android-crop as a stand alone project and it works like a charm, but I have been unsuccessful when it has come to importing it into another project.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what to do? || Could someone point me at a tutorial where I could learn how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you are manifesting your activity, `<activity android:name="com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity" />` If you already have done it then simply create files in your current project and copy paste code rather than wasting your time.

Comment: Hey Apurva, 
Thanks for the reply! 
I added the package to my manifest. 

Then added every class etc by right clicking on the project and then pressing new – java class. But, it doesn’t seem like it recognised that they have been added. 

For example, I added the ‘RotateBitmap’ class, but in the CropImageActivity which instantiates a RotateBitmap instance variable it gives me the error “can’t resolve symbol  RotateBitmap’ which indicates it can’t see the class. 

I think this means I didn’t add the classes properly. What is the correct way to add them? 

Thanks again, I appreciate your help